# Trigger 500 Internal Server Error in PHP and display Apache error page

Tags: php, apache

How can i trigger **500 Internal Server Error** or **404 Page Not Found** Apache errors in PHP?

For 500 Internal Server Error i have tried following code :

```
header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error");
```

But it shows me a blank page.
How can i show the error in Apache's default format?

Please guide..

Comment: At first glance I thought this would be trivial to solve.  But it appears it's actually not.  So +1

Comment: Just to throw it out there for everyone: I was thinking you could just include Apache's original error document out of the shared files (`/usr/share/httpd/error/HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.html.var` for me) and exit the PHP script. But I'm having a huge problem: how would you go about processing the .html.var file? In Apache it's set as `AddHandler type-map var` but I can't figure out anything that would be useful in PHP.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After such a knowledge-full discussion, i think there is no php code can display the by default 500 Internal Server Error.
The solution is :
1. Create a folder named **http500** next to the php file.
2. Create a .htaccess file in it and add following code :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^])(.(*/
    RewriteRule ^])((a-zA
</IfModule>
```

1. PHP redirect code :

> header('location : http500/');

Comment: Or instead of even making the php file, just navigate to that directory yourself. I didn't get the php to redirect me.

Comment: My question was to trigger 500 or 404 from teh PHP.

Comment: If you’re trying to debug an issue it’s going to be extremely annoying when you’re redirected away from the page that is actually erroring.

Comment: You don't need something quite so hacky in .htaccess, you can simply trigger a 500 directly: `RewriteRule ^ - [R=500]`. (In fact, any invalid syntax would do the job, eg `crash`). You don't need the separate folder, you could make the error conditional in your main .htaccess file: `RewriteRule ^crash$ - [R=500]` and redirect to `/crash`.

Comment: Adding this to the mentioned .htaccess file worked fine for me `Redirect 500 /http500`

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks for detailed answer @Vin

Answer (score 21):

You could just copy the Apache error documents into your web root (or symlink them in) and use [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to set the error codes and with those documents as output. That's probably best unless you have a compelling reason not to. But in case that won't work for you, there are some alternatives (albeit, hacky alternatives).

For 500, just put a bug in your code.

```
<?php throw new Exception('Nooooooooooooooo!'); ?>
```

The PHP script will raise an exception, resulting in a regular Apache 500 error page. (But be aware of the caveat that this will only result in an Apache error if the PHP init setting `display_errors` is set to `0`. In most development configurations, this is not the case. In most production configurations, this is the case. If you don't know your production server's setting, you'll have to just test this to see if it works.)

For 404, I think the best you can do is redirect to a non-existent page. It's not exactly the same thing, but might do for your purposes.

```
<?php header("Location: /i-dont-think-therefore-i-am-not"); ?>
```

In most browsers, the users won't actually see the redirect, they will just get silently and quickly redirected to a non-existent page, resulting in a regular Apache 404 error. Of course, the url will have changed and some users might notice that. If that's not acceptable, you can perhaps achieve similar results using Apache [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to rewrite the url backend to a non-existent location.

To respond to several comments: Setting the response code via `header()` (or some other way) will not result in the standard Apache error document. It will simply return that response code with your own output. This is intentional behavior, designed so that you can have custom error documents, or otherwise set response codes as the HTTP spec dictates on any request. If you want the *Apache* error documents, you have to either forge them (as per my initial suggestion of simply copying the error documents to your web root), or you'll have to trick Apache into returning them (as per my backup suggestion).

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Nooooooooooooooo!'

Comment: Blech. There's really no need for this kind of hackery.

Comment: PHP will just echo out the exception and stop.  It won't cause an internal server error.  It only works in some frameworks because they have exception handlers to generate the internal server error on an uncaught exception

Comment: @webarto, that's because you're running it in development with stack traces and error messages shown. In a production server (assuming a non-leaky configuration), the errors won't be displayed; apache will just return a standard 500 page.

Comment: @CameronSkinner, while I can't think of a good reason offhand for this kind of hackery, why denounce it outright? Maybe the OP has a good reason, I'm just offering solutions.

Comment: @BenLee You're assuming the OP is using a framework (probably Zend) that catches unhandled exceptions and generates the http500 error code.  There's no reason to believe that this is the case.  Even if it is, your code is a kludge at best.

Comment: @BenLee: There's no need for it because there's a perfectly good pair of functions (`header` and `http_response_code`) that achieve the goal *without* making the code bizarre and unmaintainable. That said, I didn't downvote because this approach, while ugly, will still work. You seem to have slightly misunderstood my distaste for this: I wasn't criticizing the OP as there are plenty of valid reasons to send 500 and 404 response codes in the absence of a fatal error or missing document. The deliberate this-code-breaks approach is what I don't like.

Comment: @CameronSkinner, no, those header codes will just return response codes with empty documents. The OP wants the standard *apache* error documents. This is a hacky thing to want in the first place, and it requires a hacky solution.

Comment: @CameronSkinner, the other way to do it would involve reading in and outputting the default apache error page files referencing them by path on the filesystem. Hacky in a different way, but still hacky.

Comment: @BenLee: The problem as I see it is that Apache is not handling the fake 500 as a 500; instead it is returning an empty document - the output of the PHP page. Setting a real response code should trigger Apache's error document handling.

Comment: @Sawny: Tried it here and it just throws an error message into the output.  If you can get PHP to generate a http500 on an exception by default, then it's not configured to on my machine.  Either way, you're depending on PHP being configured to behave a certain way, it will fail if it's not.

Comment: @CameronSkinner: I just tested your solution as well.  It would have been the one I would have suggested TBH, but when I actually tried it I only got a blank page.

Comment: @GordonM: Yep, I just tested it myself. Guess I was wrong :) So now the question is, is this a bug in PHP, a bug in Apache, or a feature?

Comment: I would like to take this opportunity to rephrase my original comment: Blech. There's sometimes a need for this kind of hackery but still, blech ;)

Comment: If no php function can do this, then what are the other cases when Apache creates 500 Internal Server Error. So that i can fake those methods just to show the message.

Comment: Normally http500 gets sent if Apache tries to execute an invalid .htaccess file.  I'm sure there's plenty of other potential causes, but that's the one I've always encountered in the past

Comment: A Compromised solution is : create a folder and just keep it one .htaccess file in it and add following code in htaccess file : <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 RewriteRule ^])(.(*/
 RewriteRule ^])((a-zA
</IfModule> To show the error just redirect using header() to that folder URL. That did the trick. Thanks everyone

Comment: "resulting in a regular Apache 500 error page." - this statement is not true. PHP will only return a 500 HTTP Status for an uncaught exception when the _response body is empty_ (so this naturally requires `display_errors` to be `0`). This does not result in the Apache 500 error page being served. You just get a blank page. (Tested PHP 5.2.6 / Apache 2.2.9 and PHP 5.4.33 / Apache 2.2.29). If you send _anything_ in the response body then the status code will change back to a 200 OK. This is just a PHP fallback (a clue for the developer) for when you have an uncaught exception and no output.

Comment: _"Of course, the url will have changed and some users might notice that."_ why not just redirect to a non-existing page called 404 or not found?

Answer (score 6):

```
function ISE()
{
  header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error', true, 500);
  trigger_error('ISE function called.', E_USER_ERROR);//if you are logging errors?
}
```

However, you will need output buffering ON to be able to use php `header()` function after you use any output function like `echo`.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old thread however...

You could render an iframe element into your view, and then set its height and width to 100% in the event of the error you are preparing to handle.

`<?php
header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error");
http_response_code(500);
?>`

`<iframe src="page_displaying_apache_screenshot_fullscreen.html"></iframe>`

*THAT SAID*

I truly think that the best modern solution for this would be something like:

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error");
http_response_code(500);
?>
<div class="panel-body">
    <h1>Error!</h1>
     <p>
         <?php

         // Then, in the view if your in dev env, print exception and stack trace
         if ($env === 'dev') 
         {
             throw new Exception('Uh oh! Something broke while adding a new user the db.');
         }
         else 
         {
             echo "Hold your butts, an error has occured.";
             die();
         }
         ?>
     </p>
   </div>
```

This would result in a proper error code for all users, and also a stack trace for dev if you set the $env variable to 'dev' on your dev stack.
[image: What the user sees with this, using PHP 5.4 installed with yum using CENTOS7 by default]

No redirect, no hackery, secure unless you need to expose an error it won't. :)

Comment: This is the most elegant solution for year 2020+, that works both in production, and also when PHP display errors is on

Answer (score 3):

I'm probably quite late, but this solution should work

```
header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error");
include("/path-to-public-html/errors/500.php");
die();
```

This will trigger a 500 ISE response, and show the default 500 error page, then stop the script. Obviously you will need to to modify the location  of the included file

Comment: I wanted to make this code general so it can work on any server. According to your solution, i can still do that by creating custom "500 Error" page, but i wanted to display error page according to server settings.

Answer (score 2):

you simply cannot trigger apache error pages from php code without hackery redirection as proposed by ben lee because error document redirection is handled by another layer of your application's stack (specifically, apache's [mod_core](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errordocument)).
when your script runs, it's too late.

the trickery of getting an error page by throwing an exception heavily depends on your php.ini's settings about [error handling and verbosity](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php).

`http_response_code()`currently only exists in php's svn thus it's not available in most production environments which are supposed to run an official release version.

my advice is to properly implement a custom error and exception handler via `set_error_handler()` and `set_exception_handler()`, respectively, use `header()` to send the client proper http status information and (if needed) generate error pages.

Comment: "trickery of getting an error page by throwing an exception" - This "trickery" only sets the HTTP Status code / response header, it still doesn't return the Apache error doc. (See [my comment to Ben Lee's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8687390/how-to-trigger-500-internal-server-error-in-php#comment53891257_8687401)) And `http_response_code()` is just a shortcut to setting the HTTP Status code / response header, it does not return the Apache error doc.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but when I searched on Google, it jumps out as the first answer. I was trying to figure out how to do it these days, so I think I should post my workaround from 2018.

As you all have known, no, **you cannot simply trigger Apache’s error pages from PHP**. There’s no way doing it. So the best workaround I could find, after some research, is **to use a PHP function to display the custom error pages**, which is called from both what you specified in Apache, and the page that you want to trigger 500 Internal Server Error.

Here is my `conf` of Apache:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /error.php
ErrorDocument 401 /error.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php
```

As you could see, all 4xx and 500 errors are redirected to a same php file. Why I’m not using separate files for each code is another question, which has nothing to do with your question here, so let’s forget it and focus on `error.php` for now.

Here are some lines of `error.php`:

```
<?php
require_once("error_page.php");

$relative_path = "";
$internal_server_error = FALSE;

if (isset($_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']) && $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'] != "")
{
    $relative_path = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'];
    $internal_server_error = (http_response_code() >= 500);
}
else if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))
{
    $relative_path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}

ErrorPage::GenerateErrorPage($internal_server_error, $relative_path);
?>
```

In short, it receives HTTP status code from Apache via `http_response_code()`, and simply categorize the status code into two categories: Internal Server Error and Non-Internal Server Error. It then passes the category to `ErrorPage::GenerateErrorPage()` which actually generates contents of the error page.

In `ErrorPage::GenerateErrorPage()`, I do something like this:

```
<?php
http_response_code($internal_server_error ? 500 : 404);
?>
```

at the beginning of the function, so that there won’t be any annoying “headers already sent”. This function will generate a fully functional error page with correct (or what we expected, at least) HTTP status code. After setting the HTTP status code, as you may guess, one of two prepared contents will be generated by following php codes, one for 500, another for 404.

Now let’s go back to your question.

You want to trigger exactly the same error page as Apache does, and now you can simply call the `ErrorPage::GenerateErrorPage()` from wherever you want, as long as you give it correct parameters (`TRUE` for 500, `FALSE` for 404 in my case).

Obviously, because that the Apache error pages are generated by the same function `ErrorPage::GenerateErrorPage()`, we can guarantee that what you trigger wherever is exactly what you would expect from Apache error pages.

Here is my example of a trigger page:

```
<?php
ob_start();

require_once("error_page.php");

try
{
    // Actual contents go here
    phpInfo();
    throw new Exception('test exception');
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    ob_clean();
    ErrorPage::GenerateErrorPage(TRUE);
    ob_end_flush();
    exit();
}

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

The reason I use `ob_start()` and `ob_clean()` is that, in this way, I can clear anything output before the exception occurs, and **send a pure 500 Internal Server Error page that looks exactly the same as Apache gives**, without any content on the trigger page (`phpInfo()` in this case). `ob_start()` and `ob_clean()` also **make sure that there won’t be “headers already sent”**, because nothing will ever be sent unless you call `ob_end_flush()`.

The solution above is concluded from what I researched these days. It is so far so good for me, but I’m not sure if it is the correct way to do it. Any comments, questions, thoughts, suggestions and improvements are welcomed.

Comment: +1 for the `ob_start()` / `ob_clean()` calls that allow us to start building the HTML content, but make a redirection with a `header()` call at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a function called [http_response_code](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php) that will let you set the response code appropriately. If that doesn't work (there's a note in the documentation about it possibly being only in SVN) then the `header` function can take an optional response code argument:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 ...", true, 404);
```

This should signal Apache correctly.

Comment: Why would this trigger Apache's error document? PHP still sends a `Content-type: text/html` document that contains no content. Does that just get magically ignored? Please explain more.

Comment: @animuson: Have you tested that or are you speculating? If I understand Apache correctly, this *should* trigger it's usual error document handling. It may depend on configuration, of course.

Comment: above code is showing me blank white page. and for http_response_code() It is giving me an error : Call to undefined function http_response_code()

Comment: @Forte: OK, try the 3-arg version of `header`, then. The `http_response_code` must be a bleeding-edge function that hasn't made it into a full release yet.

Comment: @Cameron: [Using `header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found", true, 404);`](http://dev.animuson.net/animuson/http_response_code.php) displays a blank page.

Comment: It is still giving me a white page. When i open the developer tools in Chrome its show me : Status Code:500 Internal Server Error. But the page is empty. :(

Comment: Yep, I just tested in myself. Doesn't work. So now I get to figure out if this is a bug in PHP, or Apache, or a feature :)

Comment: @Ben : But the solution you suggested is giving me a message in white text like : Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Nooooooooooooooo!'

Comment: @CameronSkinner, it's definitely a feature (really). That way you can output correct HTTP response codes with your own custom content.

Comment: @Forte, see my comment on my answer for an explanation. This is what will happen in development mode. But on a server, there is usually a php.ini settings that hides it and causes an apache 500 error page display (and if that setting is not set, the server administrator made a mistake). [The settings is display-errors http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors]

Comment: @BenLee: Yeah, I guess so. But that implies there is no way to achieve what the OP wants, which is a bit of a shame. I'd like to find a way to reliably solve this.

Comment: If no php function can do this, then what are the other cases when Apache creates 500 Internal Server Error. So that i can fake those methods just to show the message.

Answer (score 0):

On PHP 5.5 => "header("tester.php",true,500);" where tester.php does not exist. It works and takes me to my 500 page :)

Unfortunately none of the other methods listed here worked for me for one reason or the other.

Answer (score 0):

reason for Internal Server error 500.
I[open httpd.conf text file and edit it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Kfmb.png) fixed my error just change my serverName localhost 81 instead of 80.

Comment: I think it's better to share what you have in that linked image in your actual answer. Links are not part of best practice as they can break in the future and hurt how helpful the answer is.